Unknown Alien TV Movie from the late 80s or Early 90s
All i can recall is it was an alien trying to accomplish some kind of mission but there was a quote I can recall vaguely. 
The Alien which could either shape change or take over a human was in a Lab or medical area with Female doctor he was dressed as a doctor and the form he had taken had had a relationship (When he was a regular human) with her. 
Here's the Quote as best as I can recall:
(Woman)"We need to Put this thing to bed (quieter) figuratively speaking. So what am I supposed to do?"
(Man/Alien) "Do Your Work!"
She got Upset then I think he killed or attacked her, That's all I can remember.

It sounds like the 1988 miniseries Something is Out There, with Joe Cortese and Maryam d'Abo.  I remember the "Do your work" line.  The possessed doctor (or professor?) is writing calculations using alien symbols on a blackboard, and his oblivious coworker/girlfriend is yelling at him for being emotionally distant.

Thanks Will Feldman That was it, Had to look around but I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEvnPb1RLMU
The sound reminded me that was it! Great Answer!
